# How to design a context-specific permissions/roles system in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table for schools and a table for users. They have a many-to-many relationship.

I explored creating a permission system by having a many-to-many relationship with a permissions table and the users table, but I'm not sure about how to make the permissions school specific.

Essentially, the user may have certain permissions for school A, but not school B; the client needs to be able to look at the user and the current school that they're in (among their schools) and gather all of their permissions (specific to that user in that school).

**Is there a better way to approach this than to add a school ID field to the users_permissions intermediate table (and then filter by school ID)?** I'm using Hasura, so I'd like to implement an ideal design that can be queried relatively easily. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Added Clarification:

SIMPLIFIED TABLES
Schools Table

```
+---------+--------+
| id (pk) | uuid   |
+---------+--------+
| name    | string |
+---------+--------+
```

Users Table

```
+---------+--------+
| id (pk) | uuid   |
+---------+--------+
| name    | string |
+---------+--------+
```

Permissions Table

```
+---------+--------+
| id (pk) | uuid   |
+---------+--------+
| name    | string |
+---------+--------+
```

Intermediary Table (users to permissions, keeping track of the school)

```
| id (pk)                                        | uuid |
+------------------------------------------------+------+
| user_id (fk)                                   | uuid |
+------------------------------------------------+------+
| permissions_id (fk)                            | uuid |
+------------------------------------------------+------+
| school_id (fk) ROLES ONLY APPLY TO THIS SCHOOL | uuid |
+------------------------------------------------+------+
```

Trying to keep a user's permissions to a specific school.

Right now, my solution involves looking at a user's "permissions" (via the many-to-many relationship) and then filtering those permissions by the school_id to get the permissions for that specific school.
Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: That's a bit vague. Can you [edit] the question and add table definitions and some sample data to illustrate who should see what?

Comment: The idea of having a permissions table with user and school ref col with all the other permissions col is actually a good idea already. I see no need to improve or work around.

Comment: Added the table definitions and clarified their uses. Hope this helps make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks. It is a little bit clearer, but not totally. To what are these permissions applied? To the `schools` table? Or is there yet another table?

Comment: The permissions are created in the `permissions` table (for example, site_admin, etc.), to which the intermediary table assigns these permissions to users (users table). The intermediary table also has a `school_id` field so that these permissions are only in affect for a given school (as the user can be an admin at one school and a teacher at another, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by appending an appropriate `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM schools
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_school_permissions AS usp
                 JOIN users AS u ON usp.user_id = u.id
              WHERE usp.school_id = schools.id
                AND u.name = 'user 1');
```

That will only show the schools with a permission entry for `user 1`.